# SciPy KDE gradient

Tags: python, numpy, scipy

I am using the SciPy implementation of the kernel density estimate (KDE) (http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.stats.gaussian_kde.html), which is working fine so far. However, I would now like to obtain the gradient of the KDE at a particular point.

I have looked at the Python source for the library, but haven't been able to figure out how to easily implement this functionality. Is anybody aware of a method to do this?

Comment: Can you provide a self contained example of how you're using this function?

Comment: @pseudocubic I'm not sure what exactly you mean? Basically I would like to compute the KDE using the scipy.stats.gaussian_kde() function, and then similarly to the kde.evaluate(x) function, I would like to be able to call something like kde.gradient(x) where x is some position in the space.

Answer (score 1):

If you look at the source you referenced, you'll see that the density estimation is constructed from contributions from all points in the dataset Assuming there's only one point `points[:,i]` you want to evaluate for the moment (lines 219–222):

```
diff = self.dataset - points[:, i, newaxis]
tdiff = dot(self.inv_cov, diff)
energy = sum(diff * tdiff, axis=0) / 2.0
result[i] = sum(exp(-energy), axis=0)
```

In matrix notation (no LaTeX available?), this would be written, for a single point `D` from the dataset and point `p` to be evaluated as

```
d = D - p
t = Cov^-1 d
e = 1/2 d^T t
r = exp(-e)
```

The gradient you're looking for is `grad(r) = (dr/dx, dr/dy)`:

```
dr/dx = d(exp(-e))/dx 
      = -de/dx exp(-e)
      = -d(1/2 d^T Cov^-1 d)/dx exp(-e)
      = -(Cov^-1 d) exp(-e)
```

Likewise for `dr/dy`. Hence all you need to do is calculate the term `Cov^-1 d` and multiply it with the result you already obtained.

```
result = zeros((self.d,m), dtype=float)    
[...]
diff = self.dataset - points[:, i, newaxis]
tdiff = dot(self.inv_cov, diff)
energy = sum(diff * tdiff, axis=0) / 2.0
grad = dot(self.inv_cov, diff)
result[:,i] = sum(grad * exp(-energy), axis=1)
```

For some reason I needed to drop the `-1` when calculating `grad` to obtain results coherent with a evaluating the density estimation at `p` and `p+delta` in all four directions, which is a sign I might of course be way off here.