# how to estimate kernel density estimation of a 2D GMM and its gradients?

Tags: python, numpy, scipy, kernel

I am trying to use numpy and scipy to estimate kernel density estimation of a 2D Gaussian mixture model and estimate log KDE's gradients with respect to the coordinates.
My question is how to estimate the gradients of log KDE? It seems that the return of `st.gaussian_kde()` can not used for calculating gradient? Any help would be appreciated. Blew please see the code.

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as pl
import scipy.stats as st

data = np.random.multivariate_normal((0, 0), [[0.8, 0.05], [0.05, 0.7]], 100)
x = data[:, 0]
y = data[:, 1]
xmin, xmax = -3, 3
ymin, ymax = -3, 3
xx, yy = np.mgrid[xmin:xmax:100j, ymin:ymax:100j]
positions = np.vstack([xx.ravel(), yy.ravel()])
values = np.vstack([x, y])
kernel = st.gaussian_kde(values)
f = np.reshape(kernel(positions).T, xx.shape)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`gaussian_kde.logpdf` estimates the logpdf on a provided set of data, in your case I think it is `positions`. The gradient can then be obtained using `numpy.gradient`:

```
logpdf = np.reshape(kernel.logpdf(positions),xx.shape)
gradient = np.gradient(logpdf)
```

Note that `gradient` will not be a multidimensional array, but a list of two arrays.

Comment: If I understand the [numpy documentation for `gradient`] (https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.gradient.html) correctly, it takes the neighboring values in the numpy array and calculates the gradient from there. If the OP needs the "analytical" gradient evaluated at an arbitrary point, see my answer.

Answer (score 0):

`scipy.stats.gaussian_kde` seems to not provide this functionality natively. In [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26336883/scipy-kde-gradient/48948926#48948926) to [SciPy KDE gradient](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26336883/scipy-kde-gradient) I describe how you can add your own `gradient` method based on the regular `evaluate` function. The approach for a `logpdf`-`gradient` should be similar.